# Is it possible to make an entire website transparent (see desktop/other programs through it)

Tags: html, css, transparent

I am developing a plugin/theme for a javascript based application.  I want to make the whole application transparent so that the user can see their background through it like you sometimes see on a linux terminal with xfce (refernece image: https://i.ytimg.com/vi/532IJ7P4RGk/maxresdefault.jpg).  I have tried adding transparnecy to all of the elements including the background to no avail.

Thank you!

Comment: As far as I know, css won't be able to change the transparency of the browser's window. In order to pull that off I think you'd need to change the software behind the browser.

Comment: What have you done do far ??

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible. CSS/HTML renders in browser and you can't set "transparency" of the browser with css.